# Relation between in-states and free states in adiabatic approximation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

I've been reading the recent book "Quantum Field Theory Lectures of Sidney Coleman", which I find great. I am, however, confused about one passage relating in-states and free states in the adiabatic approximation.

Imagine your Hamiltonian can be split as free + interaction, $H=H_0+H_I$. A free state is defined as a state that evolves according to $H_0$, i.e. $|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iH_0t} |\psi(0)\rangle$, while in-states evolve according to the full $H$, but look like a free state in the far past: $\lim_{t\to-\infty}\big|\big| e^{-iH_0 t} |\psi(0)\rangle-e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle^\text{in}\big|\big|=0$.

Now he introduces the adiabatic approximation, i.e. he re-writes the full Hamiltonian so that the interaction terms vanishes at large times: $H
\to H_0 + f(t)H_I$, such that $f(t)$ goes to zero for a time larger than some $T$.

Here's the claim that confuses me: "We don't have to worry about in-states and out-states, because the in states *are* the states in the far past, and the out states are the states in the far future". He then writes:

\begin{equation}
|\psi(-\infty)\rangle^\text{in}=\lim_{t\to-\infty}e^{iH_0t}e^{-iHt}|\psi(0)\rangle\,.
\end{equation}

I believe the last ket is the free state at time zero. However, I cannot understand how this equation is derived. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Cheers